# variable data-set for large scale

Tags: adobe-illustrator, print-design, data-merge, xml, microsoft-excel

Im trying to print sheets with multiple numbers on them. I have set up 12 variables on my file that will change from 00001 to 00012 and change with each new set from 00013 to 00024 and so on it changes by twelves for each new sheet, all the way to 500. [image]

I have set the XML file that drives my variables to go all the way to 500 but I want to be able to make files that go 100, 200, 300, in increments of one hundred  all the way to 10k. this XML file only lets me save 42 files that have numbers 1-500 and no way to change it to 1-100 or 200 without making a new XML file if it is like this I would have to make 100 different XML files but that is a bit crazy . Has anyone found a way to do this without having to make a bunch of XML files?[image]

[image]

Comment: What problem are you trying to solve with this method?

Comment: the media im using lets you rip the paper at the seams giving you 12 small pieces to make paper wristbands like the ones for concerts or large events. these wrist bands will be numbered each one with their respective number. lets say I have a customer asks for an order of 100 pieces I want to be able to print the sheets the increasing numbers all the way to 100and the same for an order of 200, or 300, all the way up to 10k.

Comment: How about scripting?

Comment: Im not great at coding I barely got this far on solving my problem by using some youtube videos and unfortunately I cant find any one that has done something like this so I cant find something to reference. wanted to post my problem here hoping someone could help out.